# C char** array only stores last most recently assigned string

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I am trying to store a dictionary into a large array named spellingList.  The fgets() loop seems to work properly, but when checking what is stored in spellingList it reveals that every element of the array is zygote (last word in dictionary).

Given a file named *dictionary* that contains a long list of words in the format:

**Dictionary**

```
barbecue
barbecue's
barbecued
barbecues
barbecuing
barbed
.
.
.
zwieback's
zygote
zygote's
zygotes
```

**Code**

```
int i = 0;
int j;
char *pos;

    /* Open Dictionary */
FILE *dic;
dic = fopen("dictionary", "r");

    /* Malloc Storage Array */
char **spellingList;
spellingList = malloc (sizeof(char*) * 100000);

if (spellingList == NULL){   // if malloc fails
  printf("%s\n", "Malloc failure");
  exit(0);
}

    /* load dictionary into array */
while (1){
  if (fgets (word, 50, dic) != NULL){         

    if ((pos=strchr(word, '\n')) != NULL){ // replace ending '\n' with a '\0'
      *pos = '\0';
    }
    printf("%d  %s\n", i, word );  // looks as expected
    spellingList[i] = word;
    i++;
  }
  else {
    break;
  }
}  fclose(dic);  // close fd to dictionary

for (j =0; j < 100; j++){  // output
   printf("%d  %s\n", j, spellingList[j]);
}
```

**Output**

```
.
.
.
90  zygotes
91  zygotes
92  zygotes
93  zygotes
94  zygotes
95  zygotes
96  zygotes
97  zygotes
98  zygotes
99  zygotes
```

Comment: I assume that `word` is an array? Then you make all pointers in `spellinglist` point *to the same array*.

Comment: You’re storing the same pointer (`word`) over and over again.

Comment: `char **` is **not** an array! A pointer cannot be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are storing the pointer value, and then changing the data the pointer points to will effectively change all the values in your array.

You have to copy the data to avoid this, one way would be

```
spellingList[i] = strdup(word);
```

In other words, assigning `word` does not copy the data, it simply makes `spellingList[i]` point to the memory location of `word`, so all the elements are pointing to the same location.

You have to read more about pointers.

Comment: @LTNoodles Don't forget to all `free(spellingList[i])` and `free(spellingList)` at the end of 
their useful lifetime.